# how to Access TextEditingController of multiple same Stateful Widgets in flutter?

Tags: flutter, post, widget, statefulwidget

I am making an app where a user can add multiple stateful widgets in a list view inside a home stateful widget.
Example: list of ingredients.
Every ingredient widget has a TextFormField.
A user can add as many ingredients as wish to and eventually the data entered will be updated using a POST request from the home stateful widget.

Question: How do i access the TextFormField controller of every added ingredient widget from the home state.
Also is this the best way to approcah this or is there a better way?

```
class home extends StatefulWidget {
  const home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _homeState createState() => _homeState();
}

class _homeState extends State<home> {
  List<Widget> listRecipe = [];

  addIngredient(){
    listRecipe.add(new Ingredient());
  }

  Future<http.Response> postData(){
    return http.post(
      Uri.parse(recipeData),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Authorization':'token $token',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        "name":"something",
        "ingredients":'{"ingredient1": "value", "ingredient2": "value", ...... }'
      }),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
          child: Wrap(
            children:[ ListView(
              children:listRecipe,
            ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    ]  ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Row(
          children:
      [FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: addIngredient,
      ),
        FloatingActionButton(onPressed: postData)
    ]));
  }
}



class Ingredient extends StatefulWidget {
  const Ingredient({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _IngredientState createState() => _IngredientState();
}

class _IngredientState extends State<Ingredient> {
  final _typeController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 22, top: 20, right: 15),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Process",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Nunito',
                    color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                    fontSize: 12,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 45,
              child: TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                maxLines: null,
                controller: _typeController,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontFamily: 'Nunito'),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Enter Process',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade400),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl:dr**

- Add final String property to your StatefulWidget
- in initState assign value of property to TextEditingController:
  `textEditingController.text = widget.stringValue`
- override didUpdateWidget and also set TextEditingControllerValue `textEditingController.text = widget.stringValue`

---

I would suggest to add a model for your Ingredient, e.g:

```dart
class Ingredient {
  String? data;

  Ingredient({this.data});
}
```

Rename the Ingredient Widget to e.g. `IngredientWidget`. The type of your `listReceipe` should stay `List<Ingredient>`:

```dart
  List<Ingredient> listRecipe = [];

  addIngredient() {
    setState(() {
      listRecipe.add(Ingredient());
    });
  }
```

Change the body of your Home Widget:

```dart
 body: Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: listRecipe.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                      IngredientWidget(listRecipe[index]))),
```

Now change your IngredientWidget like this:

```dart
class IngredientWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const IngredientWidget(this.ingredient, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final Ingredient ingredient;

  @override
  _IngredientWidgetState createState() => _IngredientWidgetState();
}

class _IngredientWidgetState extends State<IngredientWidget> {
  final _typeController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant IngredientWidget oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    _typeController.text = widget.ingredient.data ?? '';
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _typeController.text = widget.ingredient.data ?? '';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // stays the same
  }
}
```

You can pass a Value to your Ingredient widget:

```dart
Ingredient(data: 'Hello World')
```

So you can also update an Ingredient in listReceipe with

```dart
  setState(() {
    listRecipe[index] = Ingredient(data: anyStringValue);
  });
```

and your list should update accordingly.